# Was ist das deutsche Wort für "stub"?

Tags: vocabulary

Ein "Stub" ist in diesem Zusammenhang ein kurzer, angefangener Artikel, wie er z.B. auf Wikipedia erstellt wird. Er ist aber noch unvollständig und enthält nur die wichtigsten Daten!

Comment: Und was sagt das Wörterbuch?

Comment: Das Wörterbuch, jedenfalls leo.org und dict.cc enthalten das Wort in dieser Bedeutung nicht.

Comment: Verblüffenderweise gibt es den Artikel "Wikipedia:Stub" in allen möglichen und unmöglichen Sprachen, aber nicht in der deutschen Wikipedia. Die Spanier verwenden *esbozo* (Muster, Entwurf), die Franzosen *ébauche* (Skizze, Entwurf), die Italiener *abbozzo* (alle romanischen Sprachen also denselben Wortstamm), Esperanto nimmt wörtlich Germo (Stummel)

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: Doch. Ich habe nachgesehen.

Comment: @tofro: WP:Stub leitet weiter auf https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Artikel#Umfang, wo das Wort dann auch vorkommt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Von den wörtlichen Übersetzungen ("Stummel", "Stumpf") passt an sich keine im Deutschen.

Nachdem der angefangene Artikel da liegt wie das Handtuch auf dem Liegestuhl im Urlaub, passt meiner Ansicht nach für die konkrete Frage

> Platzhalter

am besten (Hier hält jemand/etwas den Platz frei für etwas, was noch kommt).

Manchen Bedeutungen (vor allem in der SW-Entwicklung im Bereich der Entwurfsmuster) wird

> Stellvertreter

eher gerecht. In deinem konkreten Beispiel passt das allerdings eher weniger (*Stellvertreter* impliziert, dass irgendwo der tatsächliche Artikel existieren würde).

Bisweilen werden unvollständige Teile eines Ganzen auch mit dem Präfix *Rumpf-* versehen, um die Unvollständigkeit wiederzugeben.

> Rumpfartikel

habe ich allerdings noch nicht gesehen - Der Begriff wird auch eher dafür verwendet, wenn das Ganze schon ein mal vollständig war und Teile abgespalten worden sind. Für Wikipedia würde das bedeuten, dass der Artikel schon mal größer war und zusammengestrichen wurde.

Wenn einem (im Gegensatz zu mir) der "Platzhalter" nicht gefällt, könnte man im Fall Wikipedia durchaus auch einen zusammengesetzten Begriff wie

> leeres/vorläufiges Verweisziel

nehmen. Das ist zwar "geschraubt", aber dafür sogar noch exakter als das englische Original.

Comment: +1 für Rumpfartikel

Comment: –1. Keiner deiner Begriffe gibt meines Erachtens wider, was einen *Stub* ausmacht

Comment: 'Von den wörtlichen Übersetzungen ("Stummel", "Stumpf") passt an sich keine im Deutschen.' - warum?

Comment: @Jan Und wieso?

Comment: Ich meine, dass die Funktion des Stubs zwar eine Signalisierungsfunktion (Platzhalter stimmt ja auch nicht) ist, vom engl. stub aber eben auch nieht ausgedrückt wird. Stummel oder Stumpf halte ich für die passendere Übersetzung.Im Prinzip kann ein Wikipediastub auch der Rest eines Artikels sein, weil die umfassndere, frühere Information in einen anderen Artikel augegliedert wurde, oder zu gefärbt oder nicht ausreichend belegt war.

Comment: @userunknown Warum "Platzhalter" nicht stimmt, musst du näher ausführen. Meine Auffassung von einem Wikipedia-Stub ist, dass er zu nichts anderem dient, als zu markieren, dass der Artikel als notwendig erachtet wird und ihn nur noch jemand schreiben muss. Dass der englische Ausdruck nicht besonders treffend ist, stimme ich dir aber zu - Was aber nicht bedeutet, dass man deshalb auch einen nicht besonders treffenden deutschen Begriff suchen sollte. Wenn du von einem einstmals *existierenden* Artikel ausgehst, wäre "Rumpf" schon richtig.

Comment: @tofro Ich glaube, "Platzhalter" klingt ein wenig so, als würde der Stub Speicherplatz reservieren.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Nein. Nur den Platz. *Speicher*platz braucht er natürlich auch. Ein Platzhalter ist ein Stellvertreter für das "richtige" Ding. Nicht einmal in der IT, wo man tatsächlich Speicherplatz reserviert, wird der Begriff dafür verwendet.

Comment: tofro: Du hast Recht. Das mit dem Platzhalter ziehe ich zurück - ich hatte in die Richtung gedacht, die @jonathan.scholbach erkannt hat. Wenn jmd. keinen Stub anlegt für Phönizier, dann kann an die Stelle trotzdem nur ein Artikel über Phönizier treten. Die einzige Funktion könnte sein, zu signalisieren, dass man einen solchen Artikel gerne hätte, dass es das Thema als solchees wirklich gibt, im Ggs. zu Flrumbs.

Answer (score 4):

Bei allen Übersetzungen des Wortes *stub* ins Deutsche - etwa "Stummel", "Stumpf", "Rumpf", etc. - besteht das Problem, dass sie nicht das wiedergeben, was im spezifischen Kontext, der Wikipedia, gemeint ist: einen Artikel, der nur einen ersten Ansatz für einen 'richtigen' Artikel bildet.

Ein Variante, die dem zumindest sprachgeschichtlich nahekommt, wäre das Wort **Rudiment**. Es hat ähnliche Probleme wie die anderen Übersetzungen, da es heute, ebenso wie die anderen Übersetzungen von *stub*, nur einen "Rest", ein "Überbleibsel" bezeichnet - und nicht etwas, das noch unfertig ist. Aber zumindest etymologisch liegt das näher, weil es auf französisch *rudiment* bzw. lateinisch *rudimentum* zurückgeht, (vgl. [Pfeifer](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Rudiment)) was beides "erster Anfang" bedeutet. Ich denke aber, dass diese Dimension heute nicht mehr bekannt ist, und ich glaube, dass das ein starkes Gegenargument gegen "Rudiment" ist.

Eine andere Variante, die das *unfertige* betont, wäre **Fragment**; zwar wird "Fragment" *auch* als "Rest", "Überbleibsel" verstanden, aber - insbesondere in Literatur und Kunst - auch unvollendete Werke werden so bezeichnet, vgl. [de:wikipedia *Fragment*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment)

Em1 trifft in seinem Kommentar in meinen Augen den Nagel auf den Kopf, wenn er sagt, dass englisch *stub* im Wikipedia-Kontext eine Bedeutungsveränderung erfährt - die sich deshalb in den gängigen Übersetzungen von "stub" nicht niederschlägt. Deshalb würde ich dafür plädieren, im Wikipedia-Kontext den Begriff als *terminus technicus* unübersetzt zu lassen, und einfach ebenfalls von **Stub** sprechen.

Es ist nun ein bischen Geschmackssache, ob man lieber das englische Lehnwort (Stub) einführen will, oder sich auf eine veraltete (Rudiment) oder kaum bekannte Wortbedeutung (Fragment) bezieht. In der tatsächlich gesprochenen Sprache würde *Stub* wohl am ehesten verstanden und hätte wohl die besten Chancen, sich durchzusetzen.

**Nachtrag**
Und in der Tat verwendet die Wikipedia das englische Lehnwort, s. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Artikel#Umfang

Answer (score 3):

[Leo](http://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/stub) liefert u.a.

> Abriss

als mögliche Übersetzung.
Gemäß Definition im [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Abriss) ist das eine

> knappe Darstellung, Übersicht, Zusammenfassung

und damit im gegebenen Zusammenhang durchaus passend.

Comment: Mir gefällt der Vorschlag, da "stub" und "Abriss" neben dem in der Frage gegebenen Kontext auch noch andere Überlappungen hat. Beispielsweise der Teil eines Tickets nach dem Entwerten (abreißen). Insofern sind "stub" und "Abriss" ein geeignetes Wortpaar.

Comment: Ich kenne den Begriff in dieser Verwendung nur aus der Wikipedia. "Abriss" passt in diesem Zusammenhang nicht, weil das eine kurze Zusammenfassung der wesentlichen Informationen wäre. Im Wikipedia-Zusammenhang wird mit *stub* aber gerade betont, dass der Artikel noch nicht einmal ein Mindestmaß an Informationen enthält, um einen halbwegs brauchbaren Artikel zu ergeben - wenn ein Artikel längere Zeit als *stub* existiert, wird er in der Regel bald gelöscht.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Das Interessante ist, dass im allgemeinen Gebrauch ein "stub" die Überreste von etwas anderem sind. Ein Stumpf eines Baumes, der Stummel einer Zigarette, die Zusammenfassung eines langes Textes. Imho nur in der Programmierung und Wikipedia wird "Stub" erweitert. In der Programmierung kann ein Stub entweder einen anderen Programmcode ersetzen *oder* als Platzhalter für nicht-existierenden Code dastehen. Bei Wiki scheinbar nur für nicht-existierenden Kontext. Eventuell muss "Abriss" vllt auch einer Definitionserweiterung unterlaufen?!

Comment: Ich finde, "Abriss" gibt nicht unbedingt wieder, dass "hier noch nie was war, und das was hier ist, nur erzeugt wurde, damit man darauf verweisen kann"

Answer (score 2):

Das könnte man doch

> Entwurf

nennen.

Die Mail-Anwendung *Thunderbird (Mozilla)* verwendet diesen Begriff für unvollendete, gespeicherte Mails.

Comment: Gute Idee. Aber so richtig trifft das auch nicht. Ein Entwurf wäre eher etwas, was noch nicht veröffentlicht ist. Ein *stub* ist aber veröffentlicht.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: Die Frage, so wie ich sie verstehe, beschränkt sich nicht auf Wikipedia, wo Stubs veröffentlicht sind.

Comment: Der Fragesteller schreibt aber explizit "ein kurzer, angefangener Artikel, wie er z.B. auf Wikipedia erstellt wird." Das Wort "Entwurf" heißt in allen mir bekannten englischsprachigen Anwendungen (etwa Thunderbird, Wordpress) *draft*. Ich glaube nicht, dass man da *stub* verwenden würde; In dieser Bedeutung, in der eine klare (negative) Wertung mitschwingt, kenne ich *stub* nur aus der WP. Und bisher ist auch noch kein anderes Beispiel gefallen.  Der in *stub* ausgedrückte Sachverhalt bezeichnet ja auch ein wiki-spezifisches Problem. Daher vermutete ich, dass es nur um die WP-Verwendung geht.